# What is the best weapon to indicate walls in Cave Story?

Tags: cave-story

I've been wondering about this, but what is the best weapon to indicate where the walls are for places such as the hidden room in Curly's house or one of the places where you find the puppies?

I'm always struggling with finding the walls to either get in or out, so any help would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any weapon will do fine, except for the fireball since it has a very limited range.

I have always used the [Polar Star](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Polar_Star) or the [Machine Gun](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Machine_Gun) to find hidden walls since they both have white bullets and I can easily see it.

Alternatively, you can the [Map System](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Map_System) to navigate your way through hidden walls, but its not the easiest way.

Comment: Hm, now that I think about it, the Bubbler/Bubbline might also be a pretty nice tool to do that.

Comment: @kyr You can't have that gun on level 1 then since the bubbles are transparent. But yeah that would work.